# AngularJS - How to filter date in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

I have a JSON file returning a number of dates in such format:

```
/Date(1235548800000)/
```

How can i filter this in my Controller to only return the year?

I have tried:

```
 var filteredDate = $filter('date')($scope.ToDate, 'yyyy');

 console.log(filteredDate);
```

But console is displaying:

```
/Date(1235548800000)/
```

Comment: What date format is that?

Comment: @JMK - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: @JMK - In my HTML if i do {[{ filteredDate .substring(6, filteredDate .length - 2) | date:'yyyy' }]} The output is Nov 2009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
var parsedDate = new Date(parseInt($scope.ToDate.substr(6)));
var filteredDate = $filter('date')(parsedDate, 'yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P7sO64xQ1hFp69ydZH80?p=preview). You should get the timestamp from `ToDate` string. You can use something like this if all the time date has the same format.

```
var dt=$scope.toDate.substring($scope.toDate.indexOf("(")+1,$scope.toDate.indexOf(")"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var filteredDate = YourDate.getFullYear();
console.log(filteredDate);
```

Hope it helps...........!